# How can I compare two different fields in two collections?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a simple way that I can compare two collections?

What I have is the following:

```
ICollection<AnswerDetail> rfc; // Responses from Client
ICollection<AnswerDetail> afd; // Answer from Database
```

I would like to have a way to compare the two collections and check if 
the value of the `Response` field in rfc matches the value of the `Correct` field in afd

Here's the AnswerDetail class:

```
public class AnswerDetail
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Correct { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Side note: what the point of making TLA (three letter acronym) `rfc` (which by the way is "request for comments") when you can use `clientRespones` or something readable and not much longer? (especially if you have to add comments what it is)...

Comment: Can you also comment on why normal `for` is not working for you?

Comment: @Melina You say you want to compare the two collections. But you don't say what you expect as output. Do you want a set of the items that match, or just a boolean?

Comment: Hi Alexei actually I do use clientResponses but I just changed it for this post to make it easier for anyone giving a reply so they would not need to type so much. thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean "Can you also comment on why normal for is not working for you?"

Comment: He meant a normal `for(...)` loop iteration, rather than attempting LINQ magic.

Comment: "normal `for`"  like `for(int i=0; i<rfc.Count;i++)....`

Comment: Also, -1 on the question for not providing any of your own attempts on a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool RfcEqualsAfd=rfc.All(q=>
                         afd.Any(a=>
                                q.Response==a.Correct && 
                                q.AnswerId==a.AnswerId
                                )
                         );
```

Comment: You should use `All` instead of `Any` to ensure all matches. `Any` will return true for >= 1 matches.

Answer (score 1):

If collections are already ordered you can implement a comparer:

```
    public class FancyComparer : IEqualityComparer<AnswerDetail>
    {
        public bool Equals(AnswerDetail x, AnswerDetail y)
        {
            return x.AnswerId == y.AnswerId && x.Correct == y.Response;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(AnswerDetail obj)
        {
            return obj.AnswerId;
        }
    }
```

And then use sequence equals:

```
var equlas = afd.SequenceEqual(rfc, new FancyComparer());
```

If they are not ordered, then you'll have to order them first (using `OrderBy`, for example)

```
var equals = afd.OrderBy(x => x.AnswerId)
                .SequenceEqual(rfc.OrderBy(x => x.AnswerId), new FancyComparer());
```